# Display N/A if formula value is zero

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have the below formula, and I am trying to add "if 0 then show N/A" but it's not working properly.

```
Local StringVar x := ToText({SMPLODC.LCSCHD}, "0");
Local NumberVar c := (ToNumber(LEFT(x, 1)) + 1) * 10;
x := RIGHT(x, 6);
Local NumberVar y := ToNumber(ToText(c, "0") & LEFT(x, 2));
x := RIGHT(x, 4);
Local NumberVar m := ToNumber(LEFT(x, 2));
x := RIGHT(x, 2);
Local NumberVar d :=ToNumber(x);

Dateserial(y,m,d)
```

Comment: I can't see any data validation code you have written here...can you post some code where you wrote if 0 then N/A

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to right click the formula field, select *Format Editor -> Common -> Display String:* and enter the following code:

```
If {@YourFormulaNameHere} = "0" Then "N/A"
Else Cstr({@YourFormulaNameHere})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put Formula on 'Display string'. Follow below steps in order to find place where you can place your formula -

1. Right click on Field on report on which you can to put formular or field that we want N/A
2. Then click on 'Format Field' Then a dialog box will open as below screenshot. Now on 'Common' Tab you can see 'Display String' Option.

[image]

3. Click on Edit Icon of Display String to go to Formula editor to put your formula
4. you can place formula as below -

   If {YourFormulaNameHere} = "0" Then "N/A"
   Else {YourFormulaNameHere}